# Finding Thresholds for Sales Outliers

Tags: outliers

I am trying to determine the best methods for analyzing future data in terms of the prior 5 years worth of sales data. The data is sales related so when I plot out the transactions it is highly skewed (a small number of transactions have very large values). I have taken the log of these transactions and then calculated 3 standard deviations +-, then reversed the logs to find the monetary amounts. What issues are there with this approach and what should I watch out for when looking at future data using these standard deviations and looking for outliers? Are there other approaches that I should consider first?

Comment: What do you plan to *do* about these outliers?  It's possible the very few extreme transactions make all the difference between profit and loss, so one ought to be very reluctant to exclude outliers from any analysis!

Comment: I am only looking to flag new transactions that may be considered unusual from the basis of magnitude. These transactions would not be removed, only flagged for additional checks.

Comment: Your approach sounds solid to me. If you don't consider the large transactions outliers, or abnormal, then log transformation is a great way to reshape the distribution for the purpose of p-tests and such.